# How to search a dataframe value based on another dataframe value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DFs:

```
df1:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green

df2:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange
```

Now I would like to compare the two dfs and put a column 'True' in df2 when the color column of df2 is residing in df1.

desired output:

```
Date       Fruit  Num  Color  Match
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow True
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange True
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green  True
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green  True
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red    False
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange True
```

I came up with the following:

```
df2['Match'] = np.where(df2['Match'] == df1, True, False)
```

However got the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

And tried the following

```
flat_user_data['Match'] = np.where(df2['Color'].isin(df1['Color']), True, False)
```

ValueError: Length of values (5) does not match length of index (10798)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2['Match'] = df2['Color'].isin(df1['Color'])
```

Or [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
df2['Match'] = np.isin(df2['Color'], df1['Color'])
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @ansev suggested, you can achieve this goal by:

```py
checkList = list(df1["Color"])
df2['Match'] = [True if x in checkList else False for x in df2["Color"]]
df2
```

##### Output

|  | Date | Fruit | Num | Color | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013-11-24 | Banana | 22.1 | Yellow | True |
| 1 | 2013-11-24 | Orange | 8.6 | Orange | True |
| 2 | 2013-11-24 | Apple | 7.6 | Green | True |
| 3 | 2013-11-24 | Celery | 10.2 | Green | True |
| 4 | 2013-11-25 | Apple | 22.1 | Red | False |
| 5 | 2013-11-25 | Orange | 8.6 | Orange | True |

Note that you can use `[x in checkList for x in df2["Color"]]` instead of `[True if x in checkList else False for x in df2["Color"]]` (Thanks to @ansev for the comment)